# How to use class name as type for method argument

Tags: java, reflection, bukkit

I have recently run into a bit of trouble while trying to make one of my bukkit plugins version independent using reflection. 
The thing is, I know how to make an instance of a class by using it's name, but I don't know how to make use of the class name as a type for a method or constructor parameter. In other words, I want to transform this:

```
public class Foo{
private Goat goat;

public Foo(Goat goat){
  this.goat=goat;
}
```

Into something like this:

```
public class Foo{
private Class.forName("mypackage.Goat") goat;
public Foo(Class.forName("mypackage.Goat") goat){
  this.goat=goat;
}
```

Honestly I don't know if it's even possible, but it would help a lot in making my development faster.

EDIT:

My situation is a bit more complicated than the one I presented before. That's the reason I can't actually use generics. The 'Goat' type I illustrated above is actually a class inside a package unknown to me, so I only know the class name. Therefore, I have to make use of the Class.forName method along with a small algorithm that detects the current bukkit version and appends it to the package name I already know, so net.minecraft.server would become net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1
In other words, I only know the class name at runtime. I know, I suck at explaining...

Comment: Take a look at generics: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

You've clarified in the comments that you only know the type name *at runtime*.

The type of the field (and constructor parameter) `goat` is set at *compile time*. The only way to use runtime information to create a `Foo` class is to do exactly that: Generate it at runtime. There's no mechanism for declaring a placeholder that will get filled in by a string later.

If you absolutely need to do that, some prior art you could call on would be Tomcat (which compiles JSPs on-the-fly) and Vert.x (which generates classes on-the-fly). It's going to be non-trivial (unless you're just shelling out to `javac`, of course).

**Original Answer**:

You can do this with [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/):

```
public class Foo<T> {
    private T goat;
    public Foo(T goat){
      this.goat=goat;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Foo<Goat> f = new Foo<>(); // Or new Foo<Goat>() (earlier Java versions didn't support the <> form)
```

Now, `f` expects `goat` to be a `Goat`.

It's just like when you're using something from the collections framework:

```
List<String> strings = new List<String>();
List<Date> dates = new List<Date>();
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice info and explanation on generics, but unfortunately they don't quiet fit my case. As you said, for this to work the type still has to be specified when building a new Foo object, and I can't do that as in my whole program I am working on I only know the class names of the types I want to use, as the packages change every update (I know it sucks, but that's the way mojang wanted it to be)

Comment: @dadus33: I'm not quite following, are you saying you only know the name **at runtime**?

Comment: Yup, exactly. I also hate the stackoverflow 15 character rule.

Comment: @dadus33: Yeah, you'll have to compile it at runtime then. At which point, I'm not seeing any benefit over just `Object` unless the code using it is also compiled at runtime.

Comment: Well, thank you then, I think I'll just have to do it the boring and killing way (aka making a separate class for handling each version)